# Is the correct way to connect my website to my server?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a total beginner when it comes to PHP, I have a fair grasp of the syntax but I'm not sure about the safest way to utilise it to connect to my server. I apologise that this is a sort of generic question rather than a code problem, since my code technically works.

I have a .php site doc with a basic comment submission form. The only way I can think of to connect to the server is to allow a "dummy" user with select only privelege to call a stored function to accept the comment.

If my dummy account is called `siteuser` then am I going round this the right way? This is the section of the PHP that I'm using to connect. I believe this code is only visible server side so nobody can ever see it and use the password or username to connect some other way? Or is there a sort of default string I can use in my php without creating the dummy user, seeing as the php and server is all hosted via the same provider?

```
$sqlserv = "localhost";
$sqlname = "siteuser";
$sqlpass = "mypassword";
$sqldbdb = "comments_table";
$conn = new mysqli($sqlserv, $sqlname, $sqlpass, $sqldbdb);
```

Comment: It's annoying to be downvoted without a comment explaining why. But this is [literally a docs search away](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

Comment: Unless you mean correct in terms of "best practice" or "most secure". This comes down to server configuration, but in theory you should be fine as long as your server is configured correctly.

Comment: All the documents I found require a username and password to be supplied in the string that connects. This string and doc is server side so I was wondering if / why it's even necessary to supply that? I'm going to try this mysqli construct deal with `ini_get("mysqli.default_pw")`. I wonder what that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i do is this to connect to my DB

db.php:

```
<?php
// Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
$config = parse_ini_file('/somepath/config.ini');   

//Mysqli Connection
$conn = new mysqli($config['host'], $config['user'], $config['pass'], $config['dbname']);

if($conn->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');

    //Set encoding
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8") or die;
}
?>
```

and in config.ini:

```
[database]
user = johndoe
pass = someweirdpassword
dbname = the_name
host = localhost
```

both files have 700 permissions, so only user (and no one else can access it)

also the config.ini file is placed somewhere outside the public_html directory, i'm not totally sure if that helps or not but i do it that way.

Comment: Thanks for an alternative. It does require a password and name to be saved somewhere and I was looking for something that didn't require that but I think it's not even possible?! However, I'm going to try your method, it seems neater than my own taking away some connection code from the html docs.

Comment: I guess that unless your config file which contains the access data is set to public... you are safe... you better set the file permissions to only be readable by the user in your server, which is internal... unless your server is compromised at root level it is an alternative to keep in mind, better than setting your connection and credentials in the same place.